# Design patterns

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, uml

I am trying to understand design patterns (the Observer pattern in particular). I am trying to create a design pattern for the below scenario (specifically the seconnd paragraph). I have included an image of the UML diagram I have managed to produce so far. Could people please advise on whether it is correct/wrong/adequate/inadequate or give me any tips that would help? I have tried to use the Observer pattern to model the system - are there any additional patterns that could be used to model this scenario?

> Consider the design of a system to support flight reservations and flight status
>   alerts for an airline. The system centrally stores information about registered
>   customers and controls customers' access to the information. A customer
>   maintains a profile describing some basic information including name, country of
>   residence, gender, birth date, email address and mobile number. A customer can
>   search for round-trip flights on the airline by entering the city name or airport
>   code for the origin and destination. Upon finding an itinerary of acceptable
>   flights, a customer can purchase the flights in economy class, business class or
>   first class. Upon completing the purchase, a customer can select seats on the
>   chosen flights in the class of service paid for. The system will deliver alerts about
>   the flights to the customer's alert address, which can be the email address and/or
>   mobile number, depending on the customer's choice. An alert may indicate a
>   delay to a flight, a cancellation to a flight, or some other change to flight status
>   that may be introduced in future versions of the system.
>
> At some point a flight becomes available for purchase with
>   a specified flight date. A customer can purchase a seat on the flight np to
>   one week before the flight date; after this date the flight is closed to further
>   seat purchases. In addition, once a flight becomes available for purchase,
>   its status is on-time until one day before the flight, after which it can
>   become delayed upon occurrence of a weather delay, cancelled upon a
>   decision to cancel the flight, and landed upon successful completion of the
>   flight. A flight ceases to exist after it becomes cancelled or landed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YB9lJ.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Observer pattern should be fine. Only comment is the image that you have provided is not complete.

1. Try avoiding direct coupling between
   observer and subject.
2. Instead use a class which can manage all the observers.
3. This provides flexibility to your design to have multiple subject
   classes publishing same event. In
   future if you have a new subject
   then you need not make any change to
   IClient.

Ofcourse this depends on your need.

```
Subject1 -----                                                             ---- Client1
Subject2 ----- ISubject------  Observer implements IObserver  --- IClient  ---- Client2
                                                                           ---- Client3
```

1. Observer maintains list of IClient and
   subscribes to Subject1, subject2...
   and so on.
2. Any of the subject can
   send the notification along with the
   state (subject) reference Observer
   goes through the list of IClient and
   notifies each of the client.
3. This is
   useful when same notification can
   occur from more than one subject.
   Example: Folder rename done using
   slow double click or press of F2 in
   windows context

Comment: Thanks! So in your example, IClient is the class that manages all the observers? Could you please explain how your model would work? My understanding - If Subject1 or 2 changes, ISubject sends a notification to IObserver, which passes down the notification to its clients. But how do the Clients retrieve the subject state and how do they know which subject to retrieve it from?

Comment: OK - just one more thing...when you say "Observer maintains list of IClient and subscribes to Subject1, subject2... and so on. " - do you mean the Observer first gets a list of subjects, and sequentially subscribes to each one? In this case there would need to be another class that maintains a list of subjects right? Or if the Observer maintains a list of available subjects, then every time a new subject is added, the Observer would need to be changed, which means that the coupling between Observer and Subject is still there right? It could be that I am not understanding this correctly!

Comment: Yes, you have to modify in Observer class. The advantage is you don't have to modify 'n'clients. Same is true when you add a new client, you just add to the list of clients to be notified. Client need not subscribe to all the Subjects. I believe this should give enough clarity :).

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Splendor I would not use a third class which manages all observers.

1. It adds complexity.
2. Reusing events for other types of objects will most likely result in violations of Liskovs Substitution Principle.

However, if you have a `Car` class, you can derive it `Volvo : Car` and you'll still be able to work with the subscribers.

Your design is in other words fine.

*Note that I didn't read that bloat of text that you quoted. If you need more help, break the text into parts where you think that a design pattern is applicable.*